# the conditions for a measurable function to be the uniform limit of simple functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

In our homework we are asked to prove that, on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, every function $f:\Omega \rightarrow R, f\geq 0$ can be written as the uniform limit of an increasing limit of simple functions.

However I looked up $Real\ Analysis$ by Royden and baby Rudin, and here a boundedness condition is needed.  Is it true? or the conclusion holds even without the boundedness condition?

Answer (score 1):

At least in the definition I saw, simple functions are a linear combination of *finitely* many indicator functions. This means simple functions are bounded, so if f is unbounded, there will always be a region where $f$ differs from any simple function by at least $\epsilon$.

Is it possible that simple functions in your class refer to any *countable* linear combination of indicator functions? So $\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k1_{E_k}$ is simple, allowing an infinite summation? If not, then what you are asked to prove is untrue.

Comment: I do think boundedness is necessary. I will check with TA later. Thanks!